# Is JS script loading a macrotask?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I have a next code snippet:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log(123), 0)
document.write('<script>console.log(333)</script>')
```

As much as I understand setTimeout is a macrotask and loading of the script is a macrotask too. But the output here will be 333 first and then 123. But isn't script in this example writing a  with console.log is a macrotask too? In this case 123 should be logged first.

If you could provide me with official sources where this is explained, that would be great too.

Comment: [MDN documentation for `Document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: I'd say using `document.write` is such a legacy anti-pattern that you shouldn't even think about it in conjunction with micro/macrotasks.

Comment: "loading of the script is a macrotask" Here there is no "loading". You script is an inline script. And to test tasks prefer `scheduler.postTask()` where available, or MessagePort.onmessage. `setTimeout` has a lot of quirks which make it have less priority than other tasks.